# Cannot return the results of a mongoose `deleteMany()` call in Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am using NestJS. I have a simple typescript function that uses `mongoose` to call `deleteMany()` on objects that fit the query criteria. So far so good.

```
async deleteNotCompletedClassworkItemsForExam(examId: string) {
    return this.classworkModel.deleteMany({
      examId,
      completed: { $exists: false },
    });
  }
```

When I try and return the result I get a weird error.

```
TS2742: The inferred type of  deleteNotCompletedClassworkItemsForExam
cannot be named without a reference to  mongoose/node_modules/mongodb. 
This is likely not portable. A type annotation is necessary.
```

What could it be going wrong?

[image]

Comment: Try: `async deleteNotCompletedClassworkItemsForExam(examId: string): Promise<{ acknowledged: bool, deletedCount: number }> {` as the the return type of mongoose deleteMany is `{ acknowledged: bool, deletedCount: number }`